# Teamcity SetParameter doesn't seem to be working

Tags: deployment, teamcity

As the first step in a build configuration I am trying to dynamically change a parameter and use it in the subsequent steps. Reading online, it seems that the way to do this is to call `##teamcity[setParameter`. But this doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't even change the value in the same step.

For example, I have created a test parameter and set it's default value to '1'. Inside a powershell script, I tried to change it to 2, as shown below.

[image]

But the output remains unchanged as can be seen below

[image]

I am currently using TeamCity 8.0.3 (build 27540). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**EDIT**: I think the problem might be the command you're using to set the parameter. Try:

```
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='TestParameter' value='2']"
```

--

We've experienced the same behavior. The key here is '*subsequent* steps.' **You must modify the parameter in a *separate* build step that is run *before* the step in which you want to use the new parameter.**

It's my understanding that all parameters in a build step are evaluated immediately before the execution of that step. The tokens will be replaced with the *unmodified* values of those parameters. Thus, what actually gets executed by the build agent is:

```
Write-Host "TestParameter value is 1"
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='TestParameter' value='2']"
Write-Host "TestParameter value is 1"
```

Comment: No, that wasn't it. I copied the step and removed the last two lines. This way, I am just "Write-Host"ing the TestParameter value. It is still printing '1'. In fact this was the original problem I had where changes in one step weren't showing up in subsequent steps.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a parameter update command that should work in PowerShell. I think everything else in the answer holds true.

Comment: Nope. It just prints it out to the log. I have also tried it with an '=' symbol between TestParameter and '2'. No go. Doesn't change the value in subsequent steps either. This is what shows up 

`[10:11:02][Step 1/27] TestParameter value is 1
[10:11:02][Step 1/27] ##teamcity[TestParameter='2']
[10:11:02][Step 1/27] TestParameter value is 1`

Comment: Third time's a charm; see the updated Edit. I tested it and it works to change the value for subsequent build steps.

Comment: Yup. That was it. I had tried that combination before, but I was still checking in the same step, which doesn't work as you said. But using this, it now shows the same value in the same step, but the updated value in a different step

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work at first. After experimenting, I found that the setting of the parameter must be in ANOTHER build step! It seems the parameters are only read once when entering a build step. So in other words, break out any setters to a build step that is run before they are needed.